# Where is the OpCode constructor?

Tags: c#, reflection, opcode

When I waas looking at OpCodes class source code, I noticed something weird.

[`OpCodes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class contains some static readonly fields of type [`OpCode struct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcode%28v=vs.90%29.ASPX).For example:

```
public static readonly OpCode Nop = new OpCode(OpCodeValues.Nop, 6556325);
```

That creates a new `OpCode` and pass it two parameter. but when I look at the `OpCode` struct I can't find any constructor that takes two parameter.Instead there is just one `internal` constructor and it looks like this:

```
    internal OpCode(String stringname, 
                    StackBehaviour pop, 
                    StackBehaviour push, 
                    OperandType operand, 
                    OpCodeType type, 
                    int size, byte s1, byte s2, 
                    FlowControl ctrl, 
                    bool endsjmpblk, int stack)
```

As far as I can see there is no *optional parameters* here.

So where is that constructor ? Is there an invisible constructor somewhere?

**Note:** I'm using `.NET Reflector`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently you are looking at the 2.0 version of mscorlib.  That version has an `OpCode` struct with the 11 parameter constructor.  Newer versions of mscorlib, at least with 4.0, contain an `OpCode` constructor containing only 2 parameters

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking in the wrong place.

[image]

As found in `mscorlib.System.Reflection.Emit.OpCode` (using ILSpy)